# Similar Term for Angular Component in ASP Net Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In Angular 7, there are Components. What area are they similar to in ASP Net Core/Razor? Would the similar concept terminology be View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP Net Core, it is similar to View Components. In terms of **`re usability`** and **`reduce code repetition.`**